# SSIS Foreach loop container hangs

Tags: ssis, foreach-loop-container

I have a foreach loop container to loop through set of excel files and load into database table.

package hangs at 2nd iteration. Intside DFT I have script component to open excel and read data and then load it to database table.

I tried placing a script task in foreach loop container at the end. Now it hangs at 3rd iteration.

Comment: Does it hang frequently ? Is there any other process reading those excel files or have you kept the file open ? Kindly check the `execution tab`

Comment: @Praveen it is in development, hangs form starting. I don't have any other DFT's in foreach container

Comment: Then kindly enable logging which might give u more information about the task which is getting hanged

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I have exact the same problem.